# Get path of temp file created via fopen('php://temp')

Tags: php

We use https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem library to download large files (e.g. 10GB) from FTP.

Method $client->readStream() returns stream created via

```
$stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+b');
```

I would like to optimize the system a little bit and instead of using

```
stream_copy_to_stream($stream, fopen('destination'));
```

I would like to just move the file on the filesystem. The goal is to avoid of two complete file writes (download from FTP, stream_copy_to_stream) on the drives (SSDs).

I have tried stream_get_meta_data function to get the path, but it only returns that the path is php://temp.

Comment: For small files (default 2MB) the file contents for `php://temp` are kept in memory, nothing is created on nor written to disk.

Comment: Thx for the comment. I didn't know about this. I have updated the topic. I however don't say it must be possible. Just wonder if there is such a way.