# Google Cloud Storage get temp filename (using fopen('php://temp'))

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, guzzle, guzzle6

> Similar question asked here a few years ago but with no answer:
>   [Get path of temp file created via fopen('php://temp')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438419/get-path-of-temp-file-created-via-fopenphp-temp)

I am using Google Cloud Storage to download a number of large files in parallel and then upload them to another service. Essentially transferring from A to C, via my server B.

Under the hood, Google's [StorageObject](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/e7c0c0a5be9ec005a14d0348631754932e9eb841/Storage/src/StorageObject.php) -> `downloadAsStream()` uses Guzzle to get the file via `fopen('php://temp','r+')`.

I am running into a disk space issue because Google's Cloud Storage library is not cleaning up the temp files if there is an exception thrown during the transfer. (This is expected behaviour per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php)). Every retry of the script dumps another huge file in my tmp dir which isn't cleaned up.

If Guzzle used `tmpfile()` I would be able to use `stream_get_meta_data()['uri']` to get the file path, but because it uses `php://temp`, this option seems to be blocked off:

```
[
 "wrapper_type" => "PHP",
 "stream_type" => "TEMP",
 "mode" => "w+b",
 "unread_bytes" => 0,
 "seekable" => true,
 "uri" => "php://temp", // <<<<<<<< grr.
]
```

**So:** does anyone know of a way to get the temporary file name created by `fopen('php://temp')` such that I can perform a manual clean-up?

**UPDATE:**

It appears this isn't possible. Hopefully GCS will update their library to change the way the temp file is generated. Until then I am using the following clean-up code:

```
public function cleanTempDir(int $timeout = 7200) {

    foreach (glob(sys_get_temp_dir()."/php*") as $f) { 

        if (is_writable($f) && filemtime($f) < (time() - $timeout))
            unlink($f);

    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

It is possible, see accepted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$client = new StorageClient;

$tempStream = tmpfile();
$tempFile = stream_get_meta_data($tempStream)['uri'];

try {
    $stream = $client->bucket('my-bucket')
        ->object('my-big-ol-file')
        ->downloadAsStream([
            'restOptions' => [
                'sink' => $tempStream
            ]
        ]);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    unlink($tempFile);
}
```

The `restOptions` option allows you to proxy through commands to the underlying HTTP 1.1 transport (Guzzle, by default). My apologies this isn't clearly documented, but hope it helps!

Comment: Wow I think you are right - it looks like this is buried in the `buildDownloadObjectParams()` here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Storage/src/Connection/Rest.php and in the `getRequestOptions()` here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Core/src/RequestWrapper.php

Comment: (I will try this once the next large file is generated and ready for download, and then report back / accept the answer)

Comment: @lufc did this end up helping?

Comment: yes! thank you. I actually use `tempnam()` to set a name with the `my-big-ol-file` as a prefix and then use that. That way when transferring a large number of files I can monitor the tmp dir to see what's downloading etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform Support here!

At the moment, using the php Cloud Storage library it is not possible to get the temporary file name created when using the method downloadAsStream(). Therefore I have created a Feature Request on your behalf, you can follow it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/137643590).

As a workaround, you may be able to remove the file by hand, you can get the temp file name using the following command:

```
$filename = shell_exec('ls -lt | awk 'NR==2' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d " " -f2');
```

After that, $filename will contain the last modified file name, which will be the one that failed and you wish to remove. With the filename you can now proceed to remove it.

Notice that you will have to be in your php://temp folder before executing the function.

Comment: Thanks @bhito. Please update the answer if this gets added into the library.

Comment: Will keep an eye on it and let you know about it as soon as I got an update! Have you been able to find any workaround? @lufc

Comment: Yes, see my update above. It’s ok but obviously not as efficient as it could be.

Answer (score -1):

It will most likely be the system configured temporary directory which you can get by [sys_get_temp_dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php).

Note that this will only save to file if needed and can reside in memory.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

**Edit:** Ok, the file created. Then you can probably use [stream_get_meta_data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) on the stream handle to get that information from the stream.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is going in `sys_get_temp_dir()` (in my case /tmp), but it is the file name I am looking for. E.g. `/tmp/php89089809`. And yes the files are v large, too large for memory, so are being placed on disk.

Comment: @lufc Ahhh ok... Updated the answer with information regarding that.

Comment: At the bottom of my Q you can see the output from `stream_get_meta_data` and why that didn't work :)

Comment: Ahhh sorry... I'm too tired after a long drive. That is what "should" give it to you. Not sure why it doesn't. You COULD brute force a solution and get a list of files in the tempfolder owned by the user owning your php process and compare that later to find added files. But it's not as elegant as actually getting the path to the specific file. :P

Comment: Also, in Guzzle you have the ability to set the file name of the saved file. Don't you have access to that and can use that so you know the name since you set it?